# Comparing two equal vars return false

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, reflection

Some background to understand the code. I have an MVC application, all my models implement IModel. IModel just enforces to have an int Id property.

The following method "updates" an instances of a model with the data available in a viewmodel. For each property of the viewmodel it checks if a corresponding property exists in the model, if it does It updates the value in the model with those of the viewmodel, if the values are different.

At the last point it goes wrong. The statement : OldValue != NewValue always returns true, even if f.e. both are integers, 1. Why ?

```
public static Boolean UpdateIfChanged<M, VM>(this M Model, VM ViewModel) where M : IModel
{
    Boolean HasUpdates = false;
    Type Mtype = typeof(M);
    PropertyInfo[] MProperties = Mtype.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    Type VMtype = typeof(VM);
    PropertyInfo[] VMProperties = VMtype.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    foreach (var VMProperty in VMProperties)
    {
        if (!VMProperty.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Any(x => x.Name == typeof(IModel).Name) 
            && MProperties.Any(x => x.Name == VMProperty.Name) 
            && Mtype.GetProperty(VMProperty.Name).PropertyType ==  VMProperty.PropertyType )
        {
            var OldValue = Mtype.GetProperty(VMProperty.Name).GetValue(Model);
            var NewValue = VMtype.GetProperty(VMProperty.Name).GetValue(ViewModel);
            if (NewValue != null)
            {
                if (OldValue == null)
                {
                    Mtype.GetProperty(VMProperty.Name).SetValue(Model, NewValue);
                    HasUpdates = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (OldValue != NewValue)
                    {
                        Mtype.GetProperty(VMProperty.Name).SetValue(Model, NewValue);
                        HasUpdates = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return HasUpdates;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `OldValue` and `NewValue` are `object`s at compile time, not `int`, and therefore the `==`/`!=` operators call the ones defined by the `object` class, because [all operators are `static`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). The `object` operators check for *referential* equality, not logical equality, and thus only check if the two arguments are exactly the same object (the same pointer in C++)

To get around this, you have several options

- As Tigran mentioned, type cast the values coming out, so you end up using the operator defined in `int` instead of `object`
- Call [`object.Equals(OldValue, NewValue)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which checks for null and then calls the `virtual` [`Object.Equals(object o)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which thus will call the function defined in the actual class/struct of the calling object (in this case `int`)

Comment: I'd suggest using `object.Equals(OldValue, NewValue)`, which handles the null-check for you.

Comment: Agreed, I've adjusted my answer thusly

Answer (score 1):

your GetValue(..) call returns *boxed integer* **object**, so reference type.

Hence your code:

```
 //OldValue and NewValue are Object types and NOT integers !
 if (OldValue != NewValue)
```

compares *references* and not *values*.

You didn't notice that as you are using `var` keyword, which "hides" concrete type.

To correctly overcome this issue, may do like:

```
 ....
 var OldValue = (int)Mtype.GetProperty(VMProperty.Name).GetValue(Model); //cast to int
 var NewValue = (int)VMtype.GetProperty(VMProperty.Name).GetValue(ViewModel);//cast to int
 ....
```

Comment: The returned type of GetValue could be a lot of different things, so casting to int is not a solution. But your comment on 'boxed' was great to understand why it went wrong.

Comment: @BrilBroeder: casting to `int` is because of *this* concrete question, where OP mantions that expected data type has to be `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `if (OldValue.ToString() != NewValue.ToString())`. Or if OldValue/NewValue are int-s: `if ((int)OldValue != (int)NewValue)`

Answer (score 0):

A better syntax would be:

```
if (!Equals(OldValue, NewValue))
```